# How to make a layout like google play or spotify?

Tags: android, layout, spotify, slidingdrawer

I want to learn a layout which is be popular this time.

When the app launch first the action bar not showing and a image seems above of layout.
When the layout moves towards up, action bar is seeming and image is wanishing.
I want to show instance images below.

Spotify;

[image]

Google Play

[image]

I have used [umano slidinguppanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel) before but it is not enough for me.
I want to develop my library. 
So What do I research for that issue. Drag and drop ? or other idea ?

I try to tell explain everything.
The rest history.

Comment: If you found my answer useful, could you accept it? ;)

Answer (score 1):

I first found this design mentioned here by Cyril Mottier:
http://cyrilmottier.com/2013/05/24/pushing-the-actionbar-to-the-next-level/

Then I found this by Flavien Laurent:
http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/11/20/making-your-action-bar-not-boring/

Implementation here:
https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar

This should be enough to get you started on the right track.

Comment: Thank you @jmg I have not try yet , I will comment herr after I try

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the **Design Support Library** to implement a `CollapsingToolbarLayout` with an image.

Read about the design support library on [this blogpost](http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html), and official documentation for the `CollapsingToolbarLayout` can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html?utm_campaign=io15&utm_source=dac&utm_medium=blog).